# How do i check if a string can be parsed to a certain type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I have my own data type in haskell defined like this:

```
data Token = Num Double | Op String
```

I want to make a function that converts a list of strings into a list of tokens. E.g.

```
toTokenList ["2","+","3"]
> [Num 2.0, Op "+", Num 3.0]
```

How would I go about doing this?

I have implemented a function that converts a type `Double` into a `Token` type and another one that converts a `String` to a `Token` type. Can these be used for `toTokenList` or no?

I am new to Haskell relatively and if you need further clarification about the question please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Tip: try using `map`.

Comment: I figured I'll need to map a function like `toToken` to the list of strings but how do i make a general function that can taken in a `String` and give out the required `Token` element while checking whether that string can be converted to a `Double` or not?

Comment: I guess my question could be solved if there is a way to check if a `String` can be casted as a `Double` type or not....

Comment: Yes, there is `readMaybe`

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks a lot! `readMaybe` works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement an algorithm that is optimistic, it first aims to parse it as a `Double`, and in case that fails, we return an `Op` for that string, like:

```
import Text.Read(readMaybe)

toTokenList :: [String] -> [Token]
toTokenList = map (\x -> maybe (Op x) Num (readMaybe x))
```

or point-free:

```
toTokenList :: [String] -> [Token]
toTokenList = map (flip maybe Num . Op <*> readMaybe)
```

We here make use of [**`readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe), and [**`maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) to provide a fallback and post-process the value.

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe Text.Read> toTokenList ["2","+","3"]
[Num 2.0,Op "+",Num 3.0]
```